# My plugin doesn't show up in Eclipse "Show view"

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I created my first Eclipse plugin.
Plugin has one view.

When I ran my plugin project(Overview>Testing section>Launch an Eclipse application), it shows in Eclipse workbench and "Show view" menu.

Then I copy & paste exported plugin jar file to Eclipse's plugins folder.

Unfortunately I can't found my plugin view in Show view menu.

I also paste dropins and dropins/plugins folder.
But it doesn't works.

---

OS : Windows 7

Eclipse : Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers [Kepler Service Release 2]

**plugin.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
      <category
            name="String Table"
            id="com.andcontinue.stringtable">
      </category>
      <view
            name="String Table"
            icon="icons/sample.gif"
            category="com.andcontinue.stringtable"
            class="com.andcontinue.stringtable.views.StringTable"
            id="com.andcontinue.stringtable.views.StringTable">
      </view>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.help.contexts">
      <contexts
            file="contexts.xml">
      </contexts>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

I don't know why plugin be not displayed in Show view.

**Other references**

**build.properties**

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
                .,\
                contexts.xml,\
                icons/,\
                META-INF/,\
                .classpath,\
                src/,\
```

**MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: String Table
Bundle-SymbolicName: (MyPackage);singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-Activator: (MyPackage).Activator
Bundle-Vendor: Vendor
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.8.101",
 org.eclipse.jdt.core;bundle-version="3.9.2"
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Export-Package: (MyPackage),
 (MyPackage).views
Import-Package: org.eclipse.jface.text
Bundle-ClassPath: .
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
```

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Try starting Eclipse with the `-clean` option to get it to rebuild  the plugin contributions.

Comment: It may not appear directly in **Show View** menu Click `Show View > Other` then search for folder **String Table** inside that folder your view will be there.

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you for your comment. I tried to run Eclipse with "-clean" command. But plugin not found. I'm so sad (Cry)

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK Thank you for your answer. I look for Show view>other... dialog too. When I ran project, I found the plugin in Show view>other... dialog>"String Table" category>"String Table" view. But I can't found it when I export and install the plugin. I'm going crazy.

Comment: How are you exporting the plugin? You must use `Export > Plug-in Development > Deployable plug-ins and fragments`

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I solved it. I always tried export to Directory. Now I tried export to "Install into host.Repository". Then Eclipse install automatically after export. Finally I could find my plugin in Show view>other... dialog. Thank yo so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Clues:

1. Check after installation of plugin whether is it appearing in **Running Platform**.  Go to `Window > Preferences> Plugin Development > Target Platform` select **Running Platform** click on **Edit** and check your plugin. The presence shows that Platform detected your plugin but there may be some issues in your code.

   Note: I am assuming you used the Running platform as your target.
2. Instead of directly copying the jar into folder. Install this plugin via GUI.
   Export your plugin to an external folder or to an archive file. Go to `Help > Install New Software..`. Click on **Add** button then select a local folder or archive file. If there were some problems exists while exporting then this installer displays this.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I tried Install the plugin via GUI. then I got some error messages. It was so useful.

Comment: First Item is save my life. For me its worked to copy "invisible" plugins to other directory and add this directory under `Target Platform > Edit > Locations > Add > Directory`

Answer (score 0):

This may also happen if the plugin you are using expects latest version of some library or compiler in your system. In my case, I was trying to install SonarLint plugin and although installation was successful, I could not see it in View because it only supported Java11 or above. You can check out further details of it in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70033404/11754148)