# Could not create the view: org.sonar.ide.eclipse.ui.views.issues.IssuesView

Tags: eclipse, sonarlint-eclipse

I am using SonarLint in Eclipse JUNO to analyse the error but not able to see the result in **SonarQube Issues Console** and getting the error of **Could not create the view: org.sonar.ide.eclipse.ui.views.issues.IssuesView** in SonarQube Issues Console.
In .log file, Error Message is **Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.sonar.ide.eclipse.ui/icons/onde-sonar-16.png**

Kindly tell me what can be the issue.
Thank You in advance!!!

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. If there is edit your question to add the details from the .log.

Answer (score 1):

You have to start your Eclipse with Java 8.

See [SonarLint page](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/sonarlint) at Eclipse Marketplace.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still facing the createIssuesView Error, my company's system only had Java8 installed and SonarLint latest version 7.x at this time requires minimum Java11 for runtime. The latest supporting Java8 version is 6.2.0.37299, and can be found [here](https://binaries.sonarsource.com/SonarLint-for-Eclipse/releases/6.2.0.37299/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, my problem is solved just by switching the new workspace which does not hold any previous version of sonar

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem after StS update. So you have to reinstall the Sonar Lint plugin;

```html
<a href="http://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro?mpc_install=2568658" class="drag" title="Drag to your running Eclipse* workspace. *Requires Eclipse Marketplace Client"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://marketplace.eclipse.org/sites/all/themes/solstice/public/images/marketplace/btn-install.png" alt="Drag to your running Eclipse* workspace. *Requires Eclipse Marketplace Client" /></a>
```